# Find a prime number

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, prime-factoring

I just want to know this code is working properly .

```
let number = Number(prompt("Enter the number : "));

for(i= 2; i < number ; i++){
        if(number % i == 0 ){
                alert(
                        `${number} is not a prime number.`
                )
                break;
        }else{
                alert(
                        `${number} is a prime number.`
                )
                break;
        }
 }
```

But when I put `<=` between `i` and `number` I just thought that it will show different answer. Because in equal to loop `i` will also divide with number and the reminder goes `0` so it should also give prime to every number with using `<=` , but its not . So I want to know how this logic is performing correct even with `<=` .

I just expected that it will throw different answer in case of replacing `<` with `<=` but its not.

Comment: hint: `3 % 3 === 0` by your logic, that means it's not prime

Comment: check for `%2`, separately, then start the loop at `i = 3` and add 2 each iteration for doubling the speed - also, you can stop when `i > Math.sqrt(number)` - because maths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always reach 1 of the 2 `break` statements during the `for` loop's first iteration.

Your code

```
let number = Number(prompt("Enter the number : "));

for (i = 2; i < number; i++) {
    if (number % i == 0) {
        alert(
            `${number} is not a prime number.`
        )
        break; //<---
    } else {
        alert(
            `${number} is a prime number.`
        )
        break; //<---
    }
}
```

simplifies to

```
let number = Number(prompt("Enter the number : "));

for (i = 2; i < number; i++) {
    if (number % i == 0) {
        alert(`${number} is not a prime number.`)
    } else {
        alert(`${number} is a prime number.`)
    }
    break; //<---
}
```

because, regardless of whether `number % i == 0` is `true` or `false`, `break` will be called after the appropriate `alert()` is called.

Since `break` is always called after the first iteration of the `for` loop, we can simplify further by removing the `for` loop.

```
let number = Number(prompt("Enter the number : "));

let i = 2;
if (number % i == 0) {
    alert(`${number} is not a prime number.`)
} else {
    alert(`${number} is a prime number.`)
}
```

which simplifies to

```
let number = Number(prompt("Enter the number : "));

if (number % 2 == 0) {
    alert(`${number} is not a prime number.`)
} else {
    alert(`${number} is a prime number.`)
}
```

so your current logic essentially says "`number` is prime unless it is divisible by `2` (with no remainder)".

For a number to be prime, it must be indivisible by *all* numbers between 1 and itself so you can't know if `number` is prime until after the `for` loop has finished. Therefore, you need a new variable (such as `let foundDivisor = false;`) declared above the `for` loop to keep track of whether or not any such divisor was found. During each iteration you can do `foundDivisor = true;` if `number` is divisible by `i` (else do nothing). Then, after the `for` loop, you can use `!foundDivisor` to check if the `number` was prime or not.